# Meaning of playlists in Far Cry 4

Tags: xbox-one, far-cry-4

When I start Far Cry 4 on my XBox One the initial loading screen shows `"Playlists downloaded"`as message for a short time. What is exactly are those playlists?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume they have to do with the playlists in multiplayer. That's what my best guess would be, I can't think of any other playlists that would be loaded at the start up of the game.